# Single excel sheet with multiple tables Laravel/Excel

Tags: excel, laravel

I am currently using Maatwebsite's Excel package and am able to generate a single table nicely with columns and values that I want but I want to be able to generate tables, with other tables underneath within a single excel sheet. Is it possible?

[image: Current Result]

The screenshot that is attached above is the excel file that I am able to generate for now and the screenshot below is an example of the excel file I want to generate, with tables underneath another table. Is there a way to do this within a single Excel Export class?

[image: Wanted result]

Comment: in the `collection()` method of the export class, can you return a collection of collections?  https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/collection.html

Comment: I think I am already returning a collection of collections this is my return collect method -> "return collect([
            $level_one_array,
            $level_two_array,
            $level_three_array,
        ]);" but how do I have multiple tables in a single excel sheet with different headings and diff no of columns like the second screenshot I attached? Cuz I can't find anything similar in the documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you are going to find a way to do this using just Laravel Excel — most people would create a new sheet for each dataset.  But ultimately, you can format the data however you like if you build your output array manually.

Here's one way you could do it.

**Controller**
Pass in the arrays directly to the export class, instead of a collection.

```php
$arrays = [$level_one_array, $level_two_array, $level_three_array];

return Excel::download(new YourExportClass($arrays), 'YourFilename.xlsx');
```

**Export**
Build an output array corresponding to your desired layout, then wrap it in a collection.

```php
class YourExportClass implements FromCollection
{
    use Exportable;

    private $collection;

    public function __construct($arrays)
    {
        $output = [];

        foreach ($arrays as $array) {
            // get headers for current dataset
            $output[] = array_keys($array[0]);
            // store values for each row
            foreach ($array as $row) {
                $output[] = array_values($row);
            }
            // add an empty row before the next dataset
            $output[] = [''];
        }

        $this->collection = collect($output);
    }

    public function collection()
    {
        return $this->collection;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want to export your data in spreadsheet in desire format then you could grab the collection and send it to view and display as per your requirement.
here is the docs to export as excel from view :
https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.0/exports/from-view.html
Hope this Helps

Comment: I know it's 2 years later but just wanted to say for anyone else Googling that this works.

Comment: So you have to make multiple tables in the view?

Comment: @sdeav It does not matter. You can create as many as table you want. Its a view so you can append any thing over there.